# Get data from sub-collections in Firebase Firestore using nested query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have following data structure in firestore:

- flights [collection]

  - user1 [doc]

    - userFlights [sub collection]

      - flight 1
      - flight 2
      - flight 3
  - user2 [doc]

    - userFlights [sub collection]

      - flight 1
      - flight 2
      - flight 3

In order to read the data from all userFlights subcollections i use nested query as shown below.

My question: Would nested queries cause performance issues?

```
const userFlightRef = query(collection(db, "flights"));
const userUidDoc = await getDocs(userFlightRef);
userUidDoc.forEach(async userDoc => {
  const userFlightsQuery = query(collection(db, "flights/" + userDoc.id + "/userFlights"))
  const userFlights = await getDocs(userFlightsQuery);
  userFlights.forEach(flyer => {
     console.log(flyer.data());
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to search all `userFlights` collections, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

You can get all documents from all `userFlights` collections with:

```
getDocs(collectionGroup(db, "userFlights"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank for your quick answer.